# Google map autocomplate in Angular

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-autocomplete

I am able to use `google map` autocomplete in `HTML` but when I tried to use it in `ng-template` it worked behind I see in the network but I cant see the dropdown result.

```
    <ng-template>
            <input ngx-google-places-autocomplete [options]='options' #placesRef="ngx-places" 
            (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)"/>
    </ng-template>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue with CSS. It was working behind the `ng-template`. I added below code.

```
  ::ng-deep .pac-container {
      z-index: 100000;
  }
```